# oracle pl sql how to check if an xml tag is empty or not

Tags: xml, oracle

In my xml input string I have a specific tag which might be null sometimes. But I need to determine if its currently null or not. I can check if that node exists or not by following line:

```
IF xmlData.existsnode('/employees/employee/part_time/epart_department_2/text()')>0 THEN  
-- check if that tag has any values or not
END IF;
```

But I need to check if that tag has any value or not. How do I do it? Any suggestions?

Comment: You do actually need to distinguish between null and not existing, or do you just want to see if the node exists and is not null? Also from the snippet you may have multiple employees and so multiple matching nodes; if so do you want to know if *any* exist and are not null; or a specific one; or a count of not-nulls?

Comment: I know that node exists. But I want to find out if its null or not. How could I do that?